# Spring MVC - viewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is my situation, I am tasked to enhance an existing app which is written in DOJO/Spring MVC.

Looking at existing code, app-servlet.xml file uses

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>.
```

There are no other view mappings  (existing app very simple navigation, mostly index.jsp per component etc).

The new functionality I need add required navigating between multiple pages. My question is,

how can I add new view resolver/mappings without impacting existing application.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add another implementation of `ViewResolver` to your context. Have it implement `org.springframework.core.Ordered` if needed and set the order to `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`. This view resolver could handle views specific to your case. If other viewResolver should resolve the view name have `resolveViewName()` return `null` so it will use the next `ViewResolver` in the chain.